# Jmeter Multiple SampleResult for AbstractJavaSamplerClient

Tags: java, jmeter

I wrote a custom Java Request which extends the `AbstractJavaSamplerClient` to measure the performance of a JAVA API invocation. However, now i need to measure the performance for a multiple API which is part of the same use case.

i.e.

```
Server severInst = new Server();
severInst.api1(); 
severInst.api2();
severInst.api3();
```

Need to get the metrics in Jmeter for each API invocation (api1, api2, api3). However, I cannot split those API calls since the api2 call is dependent on api1. (same for api3 which depends on api2). If i could split then I can write a different "Java Sampler Client" for each API. Since all these apis are inter-dependent i have to invoke all of them at once.

The method `runTest` returns only one `SampleResult`. However, I am in need of a situation where I need to return the multiple SampleResult. I tried the `SampleResult.setParent()` and `SampleResult.storeSubResult()` but no luck.

Any pointer on this will be helpful?

Thanks

Comment: Having same question here. It's unbelievable there's no way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about creating three different tests. Each one collects the time for the required apis. So, in test 1 you'd have:

```
startTiming();
api1();
api2();
api3();
completeSample();
```

Then in the second test:

```
api1();
startTiming();
api2();
api3();
completeSample();
```

and so on.

Comment: Yep. I went with this approach only.